WHM Cpanel redis keeps shutting down after exit of ssh
I am hosting a whm and cpanel on a ubuntu.
Installed redis via containers.
Followed the guide on how to install redis cache on:

https://docs.cpanel.net/ea4/containers/redis-via-containers/

Redis cache server works when i am corrected with ssh.
But every time i close the console, the redis.sock gets deleted/stopped.
When i connect again redis.sock gets created/started again.
Would be awesome if i can close the console without closing the redis server.
Anyone have a clue on how to fix it so the redis server keeps running?
Have been trying to locate the master redis.conf but with no luck.
Also searching thought the internet for aswers, still no luck.

Got it fixed by using:
Redis cpanel plugin
